# LiveWallpaper Andengine example error

Tags: android, andengine

I downloaded the [andengine live wallpaper example](http://code.google.com/p/andenginelivewallpaperextensionexample/source/browse/#hg/src/org/anddev/wallpaper/live/cigarette) but it has a problem. It shows these error:

```
08-18 04:38:52.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-18 04:38:52.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service org.anddev.wallpaper.live.cigarette.LiveWallpaperService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.anddev.wallpaper.live.cigarette.LiveWallpaperService in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/org.anddev.wallpaper.live.cigarette-1.apk]
08-18 04:38:52.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3063):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:1950)
08-18 04:38:52.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3063):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:121)
08-18 04:38:52.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3063):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:997)
08-18 04:38:52.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3063):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-18 04:38:52.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3063):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-18 04:38:52.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3063):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
08-18 04:38:52.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3063):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-18 04:38:52.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3063):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-18 04:38:52.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3063):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
08-18 04:38:52.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3063):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
08-18 04:38:52.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3063):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-18 04:38:52.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.anddev.wallpaper.live.cigarette.LiveWallpaperService in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/org.anddev.wallpaper.live.cigarette-1.apk]
08-18 04:38:52.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3063):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
08-18 04:38:52.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3063):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
08-18 04:38:52.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3063):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
08-18 04:38:52.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3063):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:1947)
08-18 04:38:52.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3063):     ... 10 more
```

here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="org.anddev.wallpaper.live.cigarette"
      android:versionCode="4"
      android:versionName="1.0.3">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <service 
            android:name="LiveWallpaperService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:label="@string/service_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER">
            <intent-filter android:priority="1" >
                <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data 
                android:name="android.service.wallpaper" 
                android:resource="@xml/wallpaper" />
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I Dont have any idea what this error means. I hope someone can help me here to run this thing.. Thank You..

Comment: which version of andengine lib are you using? 1.0 or 2.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error is `ClassNotFoundException` and it is in about your live wallpaper(`org.anddev.wallpaper.live.cigarette`).So I guess that your declaration of live wallpaper in `manifest` is incorrect(for example it may be not in application tag,...)
You can see more details in about declaring a service in the manifest in these pages:
developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html
developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

**Edit**:
I saw your manifest.It seems that your project has no `Main/Launcher Activity`.If your project has no Main/Launcher Activity,your services can not be registered and so when you try to use them,you get `ClassNotFoundException`.
Also be sure that fully qualified class name of service is `android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService`.

Comment: Here is my manifest http://pastebin.com/Z1U65xjE. I think this is right. Please have a look at it.. Thanks

Comment: @Tifa please add it to your question.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I just needed to check andengine.jar and andenginelivewallpapersupport.jar in order/export in build path. (Also I use fully qualified )